# Is there any way to detect the "change default sms app" dialog was shown

Tags: android, android-activity, smsmanager

I'm working on restoring SMS on KitKat or above, I managed to show the "change the default SMS app" dialog by below code :

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Telephony.Sms.Intents.ACTION_CHANGE_DEFAULT);
sendIntent.putExtra(Telephony.Sms.Intents.EXTRA_PACKAGE_NAME, context.getPackageName());
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

of course the dialog was shown, but after user pressed Home button on phone that dialog was dismissed, thus I want to detect whether that dialog was shown or not, and `re-show` it.

I've tried to estimating the top Running Task is **com.android.settings** to do it :

```
private static boolean isInFront(Context context) {
    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> tasks = am.getRunningTasks(1);
    if (!tasks.isEmpty()) {
        String packageName = tasks.get(0).topActivity.getPackageName();
        return "com.android.settings".equals(packageName);
    }
    return false;
}
```

It helped but obvious not quite accurately, it seems not a good way when I read the [documentation of that Method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningTasks%28int%29).

Does anybody knew a way to do it, please help me for this, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. 
1) You can use startActivityForResult and check the result code.

```
static final int REQUEST_CODE_SMS_DEFAULT_DIALOG = REQUEST_CODE_FIRST_USER;  // The request code

public void startActivity() {
    Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Telephony.Sms.Intents.ACTION_CHANGE_DEFAULT);
    sendIntent.putExtra(Telephony.Sms.Intents.EXTRA_PACKAGE_NAME, context.getPackageName());
    startActivityForResults(sendIntent, REQUEST_CODE_SMS_DEFAULT_DIALOG);
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // Check which request we're responding to
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_SMS_DEFAULT_DIALOG) {
        // Make sure the request was successful
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // The user picked a default app.
            // The Intent's data identifies which app was selected.

            // Do something you want here.
        } else {
            // Launch the activity again.
        }
    }
}
```

2) You can capture the closing action.

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();  // Always call the superclass method first

    // Check whatever you want here.
}
```

Comment: unfortunately, the result won't return when you pressed Home button to dismiss that dialog, means onActivityResult() won't perform. besides, where can I put the onPause() in? I haven't any Activity for this.

Comment: You do. Your fragment is located inside an activity. If you didn't start any new activity, you override MainActivity.java's onPause().

Comment: onPause() invoked once we show the Dialog, make not sense to do anything with it.

Comment: onPause() is the first to be called before onStop() & onDestroy().

Comment: You can post your entire code here and I'll try to help.

Comment: during onPause() called, the Dialog just shown, does not means the Dialog close by user pressed Home button, I still don't understand why you convince it can help.

Comment: You wanted to check whether the user chose something after the dialog showed up,  or just dismissed it somehow. Right?

Comment: when onCreate() is called, you can check whether a result returned or not. If not - the window was dismissed. Here is a list of the possible results: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Telephony.Sms.Intents.html

Comment: you understand me really wrong, pay much attention on my question please

Comment: I'm sorry. If you want you can try to describe it to me and I'll do my best to help